# Radiative Cooling for Residential

Tags: energy-efficiency, cooling

I've seen a lot of references to films which radiate heat from an underlying surface out into space. For example:

1. http://radi-cool.com/
2. https://arpa-e.energy.gov/technologies/projects/passive-radiative-cooling-film
3. https://www.skycoolsystems.com/

Some papers/companies seem to claim this technology could be sufficient to cool a house with only the energy usage of a small pump to circulate coolant. But are any of these technologies available for residential use yet? Every company I have found only does commercial.